# Bias matrix in shadow mapping confuse

Tags: opengl, shadow, shadow-mapping

I have confused about bias matrix in shadow mapping. According this question: [bias matrix in shadow mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396178/bias-matrix-in-shadow-mapping), bias matrix is used to scale down and translate to [0..1]x and [0..1]y. So I image that if we don't use bias matrix, the texture would be filled by only 1/4 scene size? Is that true? Or are there some magic here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not entirely, but the result is the same. As the answer from the question you linked said. After the w divide your coordinates are in NDC space, ergo in the range [-1, 1] (x, y and z). Now when you're sampling from a texture the coordinates you should give are in 'texture space', and OpenGL defined that space to be in the range [0, 1] (at least for 2D textures). x=0 y=0 being the bottom left of the texture, and x=1 y=1 the top right of the texture.

This means, *when you are going to sample from your rendered depth texture*, you have to transform your calculated texture coordinates from [-1, 1] to [0, 1]. If you don't do this, the texture will be fine, but only a quarter of your coordinates will fall in the range you actually want to sample from.

You *don't want to bias the objects to be rendered to the depth texture*, as OpenGL will transform the coordinates from NDC to window coordinates (the window being your texture in this case, use `glViewport` for the correct transformation) for you.

To apply the bias to your texture coordinates you can use a texture bias matrix, and multiply it by your projection matrix, so the shaders don't have to worry about it. The post you linked already gave that matrix:

```
const GLdouble bias[16] = {
  0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0};
```

Provided your matrices are column major this matrix should transform [-1, 1] to [0, 1], it will first multiply by 0.5 and then add 0.5. If your matrices are row major you should simply transpose the matrix and you're good to go.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for enthusiasm answer. I got it :D

Comment: Thanks for noting that your matrix is column major - people often omit that part ;)